# How to determine the area of the paraboloid enclosed by the cone?

Tags: integration, surfaces

Is it possible to determine the exact area of the paraboloid that falls inside the cone?
I've been trying for days without success...

[image: Cone intersecting Paraboloid, with formulas]

Comment: Do you know any multivariable calculus?

Comment: I studied this in university but that's long ago :-) So, yes.

Comment: Did you mean for your parabloid to have the equation $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}$ (as you have it it's a cone)?

Comment: Yes! It is a mistake in the figure. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**
This is a surface integral: $$\iint_A 1\  ds=\iint_T\sqrt{\left( \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left( \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}\ dxdy,$$
where
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a},\ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{2a},\ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{2a}$$
the paraboloid and its partial derivatives and  $$T=\{x,y:z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}\text{ and }x^2+(z-a)^2=\left(\frac{R_s}{r_{\theta}}\right)^2y^2\}=$$
$$=\{x,y:x^2+(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}}-a)^2=\left(\frac{R_s}{r_{\theta}}\right)^2y^2\},$$
that is, the shadow of the patch ($A$) on the surface formed by the paraboloid and the cone.

Having said all that "all you need to do" is to evaluate the little integral below:

$$\iint_T\sqrt{\left( \frac{x}{2a}\right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{2a}\right)^2+1}\ dxdy.$$

The toughest part is to reorganize $T$ so the integration could be actually performed...

Regarding $T$: one can realize that the equation describing the shadow can be written in the following form:

$$ex^4+fx^2+gx^2y^2+hy^2+i^4+j=0,$$

where the constants depend on $a, \text{ and } \theta$. The good news is that $x$ does not appear in the equation. Now, substitute $u=x^2$. The result is a nice second order equation in $u$:

$$eu^2+u(f+gy^2)+hy^2+iy^4+j=0.$$

If you consider $y$ to be a constant then you can solve this equation for $u$, and as a result, for $x$. The last step before integrating is to see the range of $y$ (We already know the lower bound $y_1=r_{\theta}\ $.) So, you are going to have an integral of the form:

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\left(\int_{x_1(y)}^{x_2(y)}\cdots \ \ dx\right)dy,$$

where $x_1(y)$ and $x_2(y)=...$ are the solutions of the equation above. This my be more complicated than I described, but it is certainly doable.

Now, somebody will have to work hard...

Comment: Thanks. I was following the same approach until I started wondering if it is possible to reorganize _T_ in an useful way...

Comment: Oops! Then we are in the same shoes. I , unfortunately, do not have enough time (and energy) to help you any further :(

Comment: I had an idea, so I edited...

Comment: I later noticed that what was required was the area of the shadow in the x-y plane. Slightly easier to get even though I ended up using numerical methods (diverging integral)... Anyway, your answer gave me motivation to further tackle the problem so I mark it right :-)